# Show different div if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick

I have this issue with checkboxes and show divs onclick.

My code:

```
$('.check').change(function(){
if(this.checked)
$('.box').fadeIn('slow');

});
```

Is there a way to show a different div without adding different classes on html? Maybe with data-ref?
    http://jsfiddle.net/wolfovs/jqksy648/

Comment: Many ways, one of them: `$(this).next('.box').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: search well before you ask

Comment: @Josemon you could say `please search well before ask`. magic word is always useful

Answer (score 1):

may be you need this

```
$('.check').change(function () {

    $(this).next('.box').slideToggle(this.checked);

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jqksy648/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that inside your event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element on which the currently executing method was invoked.

From there you can construct a selector, which references the appropriate element to display / hide:

```
$(this).next('.box')
```

Here, `$(this)` is the checkbox and `.next('.box')` references the immediate sibling with a class of ".box".

You can then call any of the toggle methods on it, passing its checked state (which evaluates to true or false), so that the correct action is performed.

```
$(this).next('.box').toggle(this.checked);
```

This works, as when `.toggle()` is called with a Boolean it indicates whether to show or hide the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.check').each(function (i) {
        var $this = this;
        $(this).on("change", function () {
            $this.checked ? $(".box").eq(i).fadeIn("slow") : $(".box").eq(i).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

This way it doesn't matter if the *boxes* aren't `next` to the `input` element, which could be convenient for layout purposes.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cztz9dbb/)**